# Configuring column in Jira - Column Management

Tags: jira

Not so sure why some of my board has both "Add Status" and "Add column" button. But some board doesn't.

Board 1:
[image]

Board 2:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that it is because of the `Simplify Workflow`. When I use the as same as above, now I can see both buttons.